# How to prevent kdevelop showing "Unable to load the project file ...." for non-existing project

Tags: ubuntu, kdevelop

When I start kdevelop (4.3.1) on Ubuntu (12.04) it is always showing a message twice

```
Unable to load the project file ...
```

I once created a project kdevelop is trying to find, but I moved files around and now the project's location has changed. As this project is not important at all, I want kdevelop to prevent looking for this project at the non-existing location. Can I configure kdevelop accordingly to 'remove' the project from a 'look-up' list? Or can I edit a kdevelop configuration file to tahe the project out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug. Please report it at [bugs.kde.org](http://bugs.kde.org).

As a workaround you can create a new session - that won't contain any open files.
(and delete the old one)

Comment: I think I once created a project, but I moved files around so the  location of the project-file has moved. What can I do to prevent kdevelop from looking for this project. I am not sure its a bug, I could believe this is stored in some startup file, and each time I start kdevelop it is looking for this project. I will update the original question to make this more clear.

Comment: the workaround still works. the list on opened projects in in /.kde4-svn/share/apps/kdevelop/sessions/{00939c1b-ddae-4d85-9250-782ece46ec27}/sessionrc ([General Options] -> Open Projects)

Answer (score -1):

Just change the permission of the project directory where you want to create the configuration file.

```
chmod -R 777 source_directory_path
```